# Delivering a C2DM to SMS inbox

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to deliver messages received via C2DM to the phones SMS inbox and have concluded that this may be possible by fooling Android into thinking the C2DM is a genuine SMS and let it work its magic on it.

I have traced through a fair bit of the Android source code and nothing remarkable happens in the phone stack prior to an SMS_RECEIVED intent being fired off which has led me to believe that the easiest way of doing this is to create a PDU from the c2DM payload and fire off a SMS_RECEIVED intent which should in theory cause the standard SMS application to consume it and write it away to the SMS inbox.

The code snippet below is a proof of concept - I have hard coded a PDU to test the code out. The PDU is valid and was generated using a utility.

It does not appear to work and I was wondering if I am doing something obviously wrong or whether going down this route is a non-starter.

```
String pdu = "07911326040000F0040B911346610089F60000208062917314080CC8F71D14969741F977FD07";                
byte[][] pdus = null;

pdus = new byte[1][];
pdus[0] = hexStringToByteArray(pdu);
Intent intent = new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
intent.putExtra("pdus", pdus);
intent.putExtra("format", "3gpp");

MyAndroidAppActivity.this.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, "android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS");
```

Any help or comments would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AOSP Messaging app ignores spoofed `Intents` like yours, as [it requires that the sender hold the `BROADCAST_SMS` permission](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml), which [can only be held by firmware](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml) (or apps signed with the firmware's signing key).

Comment: Thank you for a very helpful and informative post. It makes perfect sense that certain intents should be restricted to the OS. I have a backup plan which is to write directly to the SMS inbox which I know it is undocumented, liable to break and is not big or clever. My guess is that this will bypass the notification mechanism so messages will be saved but no UI notifications will be raised. I guess that the only way to prove this is to give it a try!